# Break the broken hash

Tags: cryptography, programming-puzzle

Some time ago, I found this unused hash function (written in Java) in our codebase:

```java
long hashPassword(String password)
{
    password = password.toUpperCase();
    long hash = 0;
    int multiplier = 13;
    for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++)
    {
        hash += hash * multiplier + (short)password.charAt(i);
        multiplier++;
    }
    hash = Math.abs(hash);
    hash <<= hash % 11;
    hash = Math.abs(hash);
    return hash;
}
```

I am very happy that it was unused, because it is beyond broken. Not only is this hash function very weak with an ouput of only 8 bytes, but it is also reversible, and it collides very easily: there are many similar inputs that will generate the same hash. A friend and I worked on the problem, and we managed to create a C# program that does just that: take a hash, and show the reasonable inputs that could have generated this hash.

Now is your turn. Write a program, in any language, that accepts a numeric hash as its sole parameter, and yields all possible inputs (made of 5+ characters with only printable ASCII characters) that would produce the given hash if passed to the function above, each on a new line. You don't need to handle any specific kind of error, as long as it works for any given numeric hash.

On your post, please include the hash of a word of your choice, and five possible inputs that have this hash (though your program must not be limited to finding only five).

Most elegant solution wins, and elegance is defined as algorithmic elegance (in other words, brute-force won't win). I'll accept an answer on March 13.

Example input and output (UNIX shell optional):

```
$ ./hashbreaker 224443104
ZNEAK
Y^4Q]
\2'!'
ZMUB9
Y_%AK
[and many, many, many more results...]
```

Comment: Sorry, Not familiar with C#. What does `(short) password.chartAt(i)` do? Will it return the ASCII code of the character? `A -> 65` etc?

Comment: @Dogbert, essentially, yes. (It actually converts the character into a 16-bit value which is its codepoint in the Unicode basic plane, but given that the problem specification restricts interest to ASCII and ASCII values map directly to Unicode codepoints, you can treat it as returning the ASCII code).

Comment: @Dogbert This snippet is actually Java, but we broke it with C#. I'll clarify. For the rest, @Peter Taylor has it right.

Comment: I fail to get how you can get 224443104 for "ZNEAK". ASCII codes are 90, 78, 69, 65, 75; ((((0*13+90)*14+78)*15+69)*16+65)*17+75 is 5478988; abs that is the same; 5478988%11 is 9 and 5478988<<9 is 2805241856 (abs that is the same as well).  What am I missing?

Comment: @J-B, you're missing the + of +=, which causes your multipliers to be one too small. It should be ((((0*14+90)*15+...

Comment: @Peter Taylor: good catch, thanks!

Comment: By simple estimation there is an average of over 6*10^17 results in the range 5 to 20 characters (though the number will vary wildly depending on the number of possible backtracks through the last 3 operations), do you really want them all as output? I'm sorry, zneak. I'm afraid I can't do that.

Comment: @eBusiness I know, I know! Life is hard, and posting that many would drain one's bandwidth quick enough. Luckily, all you have to post along your answer, as specified in the question, are 5 collisions. I'm sure you can do at least that.

Comment: It's not so much bandwidth I'm concerned about, but no computer in the world has enough memory to store all the results. One really can't optimise a task that is incompletable.

Comment: @eBusiness Whatever your concern is, rest assured that you need no more than 5 with your post. Your computer should be able to handle that (_and_ your ISP too).

Comment: eBusiness makes a good point. Your spec says "yields all possible inputs (made of 5-20 characters with only printable ASCII characters) that would produce the given hash", but a program which emits one possible input per nanosecond would, for an average hash, take more than a decade to execute (there are approximately 2^123 possible inputs, ignoring lower-case a-z since they are upper-cased by the hash function, and only 2^64 possible outputs - if that).

Comment: @Peter Taylor I didn't do a very complex analysis, but I'm pretty sure a smart program doesn't need to go through 2^123 possibilities. And since I don't see any practical use of breaking those hashes, I'm at ease stopping the program once I get the feeling it's working.

Comment: @zneak, you're missing the point. 2^123 objects in 2^64 buckets means that on average each bucket contains 2^(123-64) = 2^59 objects. If you prefer to look at it this way: a program which meets your spec will output about 8 [exabytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte). You really need to change the spec to either limit it to the first N values for a reasonable N or to limit the search space to strings up to some smaller size.

Comment: @Peter Taylor I was very wrong with my numbers, but I still hope that you realize I'm more interested in the algorithm than the output itself. I've _removed_ the upper bound on input size to make it more clear: just generate values that match the hash until I press Ctrl+C.

Comment: Hmmm, well, now the specification as it stand calls for infinite results.

Comment: Which means that people using (most) functional languages have to complicate things by using lazy output.

Comment: @eBusiness Yes, it does. If you write a general solution, it shouldn't be a problem. @Peter Taylor, I really don't know about functional languages, but aren't dynamic stacks a standard feature among them? That said, if you don't stack overflow after a few minutes of running with your favorite language, I won't mind it if practical restrictions prevent you from outputting exabytes of data.

Comment: @zneak, functional languages often do output via interactive emitting of the results of the function. In other words, they don't output part-way through a calculation - so if you have an infinite calculation, you'll never see any output. See J-B's solution as an example: it's a function which returns a list of all the solutions it finds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another partial answer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Sandbox {
    class Launcher {
        public static int Main(string[] args) {
            long h4;
            if (args.Length != 1 || !long.TryParse(args[0], out h4)) {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("Usage: Sandbox.exe <hash>");
                return -1;
            }

            // TODO Handle 15-char or longer solutions. 15 chars is the point at which simple mod breaks because the multipliers wrap.
            for (int len = 5; len < 15; len++)
                foreach (long h3 in invAbs(h4))
                    foreach (long h2 in h3Toh2(h3))
                        foreach (long h1 in invAbs(h2))
                            foreach (string soln in solveH1Inner(h1, new char[len], len - 1, 1, 13 + len))
                                Console.WriteLine(soln);

            return 0;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> solveH1Inner(long rem, char[] chs, int off, long mul, long mod) {
            if (off < 0) {
                if (rem == 0) yield return new string(chs);
                yield break;
            }

            long mask = (mul & -mul) - 1;
            if ((rem & mask) != 0) yield break;

            foreach (char ch in " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_{|}~") {
                if ((ch * mul) % mod == rem % mod) {
                    chs[off] = ch;
                    foreach (string soln in solveH1Inner(rem - mul * ch, chs, off - 1, mul * mod, mod - 1))
                        yield return soln;
                }
            }

            yield break;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<long> invAbs(long h4) {
            if (h4 < 0 && h4 != long.MinValue) throw new ArgumentException();
            yield return h4;
            if (h4 != long.MinValue) yield return -h4;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<long> h3Toh2(long h3) {
            // h3 = h2 << (h2 % 11)
            // where h2 is either long.MinValue or non-negative.
            // long.MinValue << (long.MinValue % 11) = 0
            if (h3 == 0) yield return long.MinValue;

            for (int shift = 0; shift < 11; shift++) {
                if (shift == 0 && h3 < 0) continue;

                long mask = (1L << shift) - 1;
                if ((h3 & mask) != 0) break;

                long inc = shift == 0 ? 0 : 1L << (64 - shift);
                long maskBottom = inc - 1;
                long bottom = (h3 >> shift) & maskBottom;
                long top = 0;
                do {
                    if ((top + bottom) % 11 == shift) yield return (top + bottom);
                    top += inc;
                } while (top > 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are some minor optimisations which could be done, but I think it's more legible like this. (Arguably I should eliminate the enumerators and push the WriteLine in too, but hey).

Example of collisions for 199681664

```
PETER
OTTER
R(DER
Q6SVR
R*&$@
```

Answer (score 2):

I got more than enough answers without reversing both `abs` calls, so I skipped that.  They'd be trivial to add back if *really* needed.  I'm not even taking `long` overflow into account, but that'd let you insert most any word you like in the greater hashes.  As if that was needed to get collisions.

```
import Data.Char
import Data.Bits
import Control.Monad

printables = [32..95]

reverseModShift11 x = do
  let zeros = head $ filter (testBit x) [0..]
  b <- [0 .. zeros]
  let h = x `shiftR` b
  guard $ (h `mod` 11) == (fromIntegral b)
  return h

reverseBase p m n | m < 13    = []
                  | n <  0    = []
                  | n == 0 && m == 13 = return p
                  | otherwise = do
  let r = n `mod` m
  c <- filter (\x -> x `mod` m == r) printables
  reverseBase (chr c:p) (m-1) ((n-c) `div` m)

reverseBases = join . ap (map (reverseBase "") [14..29]) . return

breakHash = reverseModShift11 >=> reverseBases
```

Sample use:

```
*Main> breakHash 224443104
["]#'!'","\\2'!'","[A'!'","ZP'!'","Y_'!'",
  (...)
"[?EAK","ZNEAK","Y]EAK",
  (...)
"] TQ]","\\/TQ]","[>TQ]","ZMTQ]","Y\\TQ]"]
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript 224 LOC

This function will calculate all results of a given length, optionally limited to results starting with a given string, that is if it's done within the 1 second that I have allotted. If no results exist it is done virtually instantly. The function rely heavily on a very slow custom built 64 bit integer library, an equivalent C function would probably be 100 to 1000 times faster. I might set up a nice web interface.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Break Hash</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre id="out"></pre>
<script>
function to64(inp){
    var res=[]
    res[0]=inp%(256*256*256)
    inp=Math.floor(inp/(256*256*256))
    res[1]=inp%(256*256*256)
    inp=Math.floor(inp/(256*256*256))
    res[2]=inp%(256*256)
    return res
}
function add64(inp1,inp2){
    var res=[]
    res[0]=inp1[0]+inp2[0]
    res[1]=inp1[1]+inp2[1]+Math.floor(res[0]/(256*256*256))
    res[2]=(inp1[2]+inp2[2]+Math.floor(res[1]/(256*256*256)))&(256*256-1)
    res[0]&=(256*256*256-1)
    res[1]&=(256*256*256-1)
    return res
}
function neg64(inp){
    var res=[]
    res[0]=inp[0]^(256*256*256-1)
    res[1]=inp[1]^(256*256*256-1)
    res[2]=inp[2]^(256*256-1)
    return add64(res,[1,0,0])
}
function abs64(inp){
    if(inp[2]>=(256*128)){
        return neg64(inp)
    }
    return inp
}
function mul64(inp1,inp2){
    var res=[]
    res[0]=inp1[0]*inp2[0]
    res[1]=inp1[1]*inp2[0]+inp1[0]*inp2[1]+Math.floor(res[0]/(256*256*256))
    res[2]=inp1[2]*inp2[0]+inp1[1]*inp2[1]+inp1[0]*inp2[2]+Math.floor(res[1]/(256*256*256))
    overflow=(res[2]>=(256*256)) //Global shortcut
    res[2]&=(256*256-1)
    res[0]&=(256*256*256-1)
    res[1]&=(256*256*256-1)
    return res
}
function mod64(inp1,inp2){ //64,float -> float
    var res=inp1[2]%inp2
    res=(res*(256*256*256)+inp1[1])%inp2
    return (res*(256*256*256)+inp1[0])%inp2
}
function div64(inp1,inp2){ //64,float -> 64
    var res=[]
    res[2]=Math.floor(inp1[2]/inp2)
    var mem1=inp1[1]+(inp1[2]%inp2)*(256*256*256)
    res[1]=Math.floor(mem1/inp2)
    res[0]=Math.floor((inp1[0]+(mem1%inp2)*(256*256*256))/inp2)
    return add64(res,[0,0,0])
}
function cmp64(inp1,inp2){
    for(var a=2;a>=0;a--){
        if(inp1[a]>inp2[a]){
            return 1
        }
        if(inp1[a]<inp2[a]){
            return -1
        }
    }
    return 0
}
function string64(inp){
    var res=""
    while(cmp64(inp,[0,0,0])){
        res=mod64(inp,10)+res
        inp=div64(inp,10)
    }
    return res||"0"
}

function hashPassword(password){
    var i
    password=stringtoarray(password)
    var hash = to64(0);
    var multiplier = to64(13);
    for (i = 0; i < password.length; i++){
        multiplier = add64(multiplier,[1,0,0])
        hash = add64(mul64(hash,multiplier),to64(password[i]));
    }
    hash = abs64(hash);
    hash = mul64(hash,to64(Math.pow(2,mod64(hash,11))));
    hash = abs64(hash);
    return string64(hash)
}
function stringtoarray(password){
    var i
    if((typeof password)=="string"){
        var password2 = password.toUpperCase();
        password=[]
        for(i=0;i<password2.length;i++){
            password[i]=password2.charCodeAt(i)
        }
    }
    return password
}

function reverse(hash,start,len){
    var maxtime=(+new Date())+1000
    var m1=neg64(to64(1))
    start=stringtoarray(start)
    var multipliers=[]
    var multipliersum=[]
    var max=[]
    var min=[]
    var firstlimit=0
    multipliers[len-1]=[1,0,0]
    multipliersum[len-1]=[1,0,0]
    max[len-1]=[126,0,0]
    min[len-1]=[32,0,0]
    for(var a=len-2;a>=0;a--){
        multipliers[a]=mul64(multipliers[a+1],to64(15+a))
        multipliersum[a]=add64(multipliers[a],multipliersum[a+1])
        min[a]=mul64(multipliersum[a],[32,0,0])
        max[a]=mul64(multipliersum[a],[126,0,0])
        if(overflow && !firstlimit){
            firstlimit=a+1
        }
    }
    var startvalue=[0,0,0]
    for(var a=0;a<start.length;a++){
        startvalue=add64(startvalue,mul64(to64(start[a]),multipliers[a]))
    }
    startvalue=neg64(startvalue)
    
    allowed=[]
    for(a=0;a<32;a++){
        allowed[a]=false
    }
    for(a=32;a<97;a++){
        allowed[a]=true
    }
    for(a=97;a<123;a++){
        allowed[a]=false
    }
    for(a=123;a<127;a++){
        allowed[a]=true
    }
    for(a=127;a<256;a++){
        allowed[a]=false
    }
    var results=[]
    function arrtostring(arr){
        str=""
        for(var a=0;a<arr.length;a++){
            //str+=String.fromCharCode(arr[a])
            str+="&#"+arr[a]+";"
        }
        return str
    }
    function makepwd(ihash){ //This is where clock cycles go to die
        ihash=add64(ihash,startvalue)
        stringarr=[]
        for(var a=0;a<start.length;a++){
            stringarr[a]=start[a]
        }
        function addrest(ihash,startfrom){
            if(maxtime<(+new Date())){
                return
            }
            var a
            var jhash
            if(startfrom==len){
                if(cmp64(ihash,[0,0,0])==0){
                    results[results.length]=arrtostring(stringarr)
                }
            }
            else if(startfrom<firstlimit || ((cmp64(ihash,min[startfrom])!=-1) && (cmp64(ihash,max[startfrom])!=1))){
                for(a=32;a<127;a++){
                    if(allowed[a]){
                        jhash=add64(ihash,neg64(mul64(to64(a),multipliers[startfrom])))
                        stringarr[startfrom]=a
                        addrest(jhash,startfrom+1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        addrest(ihash,start.length)
    }
    function reversemod(ihash){
        if(ihash[2]<(128*256)){
            if(mod64(ihash,11)==0){
                makepwd(ihash)
                makepwd(neg64(ihash))
            }
        }
        var modresult=1
        var a
        var addlim
        var jhash
        while(mod64(ihash,2)==0){
            ihash=div64(ihash,2)
            addlim=Math.pow(2,modresult-1)
            for(a=0;a<addlim;a++){
                jhash=add64(to64(a*Math.pow(2,64-modresult)),ihash)
                if(mod64(jhash,11)==modresult){
                    makepwd(jhash)
                    makepwd(neg64(jhash))
                }
            }
            modresult++
        }
    }
    reversemod(hash)
    reversemod(neg64(hash))
    return results
}

document.getElementById("out").innerHTML=reverse(to64(224443104),"ebusiness",22).join("<br>")
//document.getElementById("out").innerHTML=hashPassword("EBUSINESS\"XUWL]NHHHF{I")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Some collisions for 224443104

```
EBUSINESS"XUWL]NHHHF{I
EBUSINESS"XUWL]NHHHF|&
EBUSINESS"XUWL]NHHHGYI
EBUSINESS"XUWL]NHHHGZ&
EBUSINESS"XUWL]NHHHH7I
```

Comment: Clever, clever.